# Head retention in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Reading paragraph about head retention in "Clojure Programming" (page 98), i couldn't figure out what happens in `split-with` example. I've tried to experiment with repl but it made me more confused.

```
(time (let [r (range 1e7) 
            a (take-while #(< % 12) r)
            b (drop-while #(< % 12) r)]
        [(count a) (count b)]))
"Elapsed time: 1910.401711 msecs"
[12 9999988]

(time (let [r (range 1e7) 
            a (take-while #(< % 12) r)
            b (drop-while #(< % 12) r)]
        [(count b) (count a)]))
"Elapsed time: 3580.473787 msecs"
[9999988 12]

(time (let [r (range 1e7) 
            a (take-while #(< % 12) r)
            b (drop-while #(< % 12) r)]
        [(count b)]))
"Elapsed time: 3516.70982 msecs"
[9999988]
```

As you can see from the last example, if I don't compute `a`, time consuming somehow grows. I guess, i've missed something here, but what?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994316/clojure-head-retention, which gives a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Count](http://clojure.org/data_structures) is O(1). That's why your measurements don't depend on it.

Comment: Lists count is really O(1), but according to "Clojure Programming", seqs aren't really lists and obtaining the length of a seq carries a cost.

Comment: Sorry. I've misled you. Yes, in your case it's LazySeq and "count" is O(n). On my machine (count a) took 0.019 msecs. So for your measurements it still looks like O(1).

Comment: Please, try to check (count b), because in my case it's (count b), not  (count a).

Comment: Basically using `(count b)` before `(count a)` caused the total time to increase

Answer (score 1):

The `count` function is O(1) for [Counted](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/d0c380d9809fd242bec688c7134e900f0bbedcac/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Counted.java) collections, which includes vectors and lists.

Sequences, on the other hand, are [not counted](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/d0c380d9809fd242bec688c7134e900f0bbedcac/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L525) which makes `count` O(n) for them. The important part here is that the functions `take-while` and `drop-while` return sequences. The fact that they are also lazy is not a major factor here.

Answer (score 1):

When using time a a benchmark, run the tests many times to get an accurate result

```
user> (defn example2 [] (let [r (range 1e7)                                             
              a (take-while #(< % 12) r)                                     
              b (drop-while #(< % 12) r)]                        
             [(count a) (count b)]))
#'user/example2

user> (dorun (take 1000 (repeatedly example2)))
nil

user> (time (example2))
"Elapsed time: 614.4 msecs"
[12 9999988]
```

I blame variance in runtime because the hotspot compiler has not yet fully optomized the generated classes. I ran the first and second examples several times and got mixed relative results:

run example one twice:

```
autotestbed.core> (time (let [r (range 1e7)                                                                
                                        a (take-while #(< % 12) r)                                     
                                                    b (drop-while #(< % 12) r)]                        
                              [(count a) (count b)]))
"Elapsed time: 929.681423 msecs"                                                                           
[12 9999988]
autotestbed.core> (time (let [r (range 1e7)                                                                
                                        a (take-while #(< % 12) r)                                     
                                                    b (drop-while #(< % 12) r)]                        
                              [(count a) (count b)]))
"Elapsed time: 887.81269 msecs"                                                                            
[12 9999988]
```

then run example two a couple times:

```
core> (time (let [r (range 1e7)                                                                
                  a (take-while #(< % 12) r)                                     
                  b (drop-while #(< % 12) r)]                        
             [(count a) (count b)]))
"Elapsed time: 3838.751561 msecs"                                                                          
[12 9999988]
core> (time (let [r (range 1e7)                                                                
                  a (take-while #(< % 12) r)                                     
                  b (drop-while #(< % 12) r)]                        
             [(count a) (count b)]))
"Elapsed time: 970.397078 msecs"                                                                           
[12 9999988]
```

sometiems the second examples are just as fast

Answer (score 0):

Binding in `let` form performed even we don't use this value.

```
(let [x (println "Side effect")] 1)
```

Code above prints "Side effect", and return 1.

In all your three examples used the same binding in let form, so I don't see any difference here. By the way, on my machine all your snippets took approximately equal time.

The real difference when you try something like this:

```
(time (let [r (range 2e7) 
        a (take 100 r)
        b (drop 100 r)]
    [(count a)]))
"Elapsed time: 0.128304 msecs"
[100]

(time (let [r (range 2e7) 
        a (take 100 r)
        b (drop 100 r)]
    [(count b)]))
"Elapsed time: 3807.591342 msecs"
[19999900]
```

Due to fact that `b` and `a` are lazy sequences, `count` works in `O(n)` time. But in first example we don't calculate count for b, so it works almost immediately.

Comment: In the original examples `r` `a` and `b` are immediately bound in the let statement to lazy un-evaluated sequences. Binding these names does not cause the sequences to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

the time it is showing is completely system dependent....
if you re-execute it, it will show some different elapsed time for each execution