# Clojure head retention

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, jvm, lisp

I'm reading Clojure Programming book by O'Reilly..

I came across an example of head retention.
First example retains reference to `d` (I presume), so it doesn't get garbage collected:

```
(let [[t d] (split-with #(< % 12) (range 1e8))]
    [(count d) (count t)])
;= #<OutOfMemoryError java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space>
```

While the second example doesn't retain it, so it goes with no problem:

```
(let [[t d] (split-with #(< % 12) (range 1e8))]
    [(count t) (count d)])
;= [12 99999988]
```

What I don't get here is what exactly is retained in which case and why.
If I try to return just `[(count d)]`, like this:

```
(let [[t d] (split-with #(< % 12) (range 1e8))]
    [(count d)])
```

it seems to create the same memory problem.

Further, I recall reading that `count` in every case realizes/evaluates a sequence.
So, I need that clarified.

If I try to return `(count t)` first, how is that faster/more memory efficient than if I don't return it at all?
And what & why gets retained in which case?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In both the first and the final examples the original sequence passed to `split-with` is retained while being realized in full in memory; hence the OOME. The way this happens is indirect; what is retained directly is `t`, while the original sequence is being held onto by `t`, a lazy seq, *in its unrealized state*.

The way `t` causes the original sequence to be held is as follows. Prior to being realized, `t` is a `LazySeq` object storing a thunk which may be called upon at some point to realize `t`; this thunk needs to store a pointer to the original sequence argument to `split-with` before it is realized to pass it on to `take-while` -- see the implementation of `split-with`. Once `t` is realized, the thunk becomes eligible for GC (the field which holds it in the `LazySeq` object is set to `null`) at `t` no longer holds the head of the huge input seq.

The input seq itself is being realized in full by `(count d)`, which needs to realize `d`, and thus the original input seq.

Moving on to why `t` is being retained:

In the first case, this is because `(count d)` gets evaluated before `(count t)`. Since Clojure evaluates these expressions left to right, the local `t` needs to hang around for the second call to count, and since it happens to hold on to a huge seq (as explained above), that leads to the OOME.

The final example where only `(count d)` is returned should ideally not hold on to `t`; the reason that is not the case is somewhat subtle and best explained by referring to the second example.

The second example happens to work fine, because after `(count t)` is evaluated, `t` is no longer needed. The Clojure compiler notices this and uses a clever trick to have the local reset to `nil` simultaneously with the `count` call being made. The crucial piece of Java code does something like `f(t, t=null)`, so that the current value of `t` is passed to the appropriate function, but the local is cleared before control is handed over to `f`, since this happens as a side effect of the expression `t=null` which is an argument to `f`; clearly here Java's left-to-right semantics are key to this working.

Back to the final example, this doesn't work, because `t` is not actually used anywhere and unused locals are not handled by the locals clearing process. (The clearing happens at the point of last use; in absence of such a point in the program, there is no clearing.)

As for `count` realizing lazy sequences: it must do that, as there is no general way of predicting the length of a lazy seq without realizing it.

Comment: You say "the local t needs to hang around for the second call to count, and since it happens to point at a huge seq, that leads to the OOME." But `t` is just 12 items sequence.

How can disposing of `t` play such a huge role if it is 12 items sequence.. And holding `d` in memory isnt an issue although it is all the rest of `(range 1e8)`

Comment: Well, `t` prior to being used in some fashion is an unrealized lazy seq which, internally, holds some code that at some point may be called upon to realize `t`. This code needs to hold a pointer at the original sequence passed to `split-with`, so it can pass it on to `take-while` (see the implementation of `split-with`). Thanks for the comment -- this should be part of the answer, I'll edit it in.

Comment: So what you are saying is that, `t` being held, it holds actually the whole original sequence in memory?
So that while `(count d)` is being computed, parallel with that we have clojure keeping the whole original sequence realized in memory?

Comment: Yes to the second question. For the first, not after it's realized. See the edited answer.

Comment: Only one more question. Since `t` holds a lazy sequence, and `(range 1e8)` is also, I believe lazy, why does holding unrealized `t` need to hold whole, realized original sequence?
Isn't it all lazy, after all?
I believe original seq is also lazy?

Comment: Yes, but `(count d)` needs to realize all of it.

Comment: so at the point of realizing `(count d)`, original sequence gets realized and doubles up in memory, causing OOME

Comment: Yes, and now I realize that that is what I should have started the answer with... While `t` is what gets retained directly, it is of course the original sequence which causes the problem. Will do another round of edits (and while I'm at it, get rid of some typos).

Comment: It seems that the primary reason the second example works is not that `t` is being discarded by the compiler, but that it is fully realized and no longer retains it's thunk.

For example: `(let [[t d] (split-with #(< % 40) (range 1e8))] [(count t) (count d) (count t)])` seems to work fine, while `(let [[t d] (split-with #(< % 40) (range 1e8))] [(first t) (count d) (count t)])` runs out of memory.

Comment: @allait Actually I describe this behaviour of thunks in the first two paragraphs of the answer; but perhaps it is not clear from the answer that a fully realized `t` is not a problem even if the local is not cleared, so thanks! Still, the local is in fact cleared in this example, which is why `(let [[t d] (split-with #(< % 100) (range 1e8))] [(first t) (count d)])` works fine, even though here `t` is not fully realized. (Changed 12 to 100 so that it's clear that `t` is not being fully realized in this example, although `split-with` actually isn't chunk aware, so this doesn't really matter.)

Answer (score 26):

Answer by @Michał Marczyk, while correct, is a little difficult to comprehend. I find [this post on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/bTAYeLXc25w/gBKY2GWGUoQJ) easier to grasp.

Here's how I understand it:

**Step 1** Create lazy sequence: `(range 1e8)`. Values are not realized yet, I marked them as asterixes (`*`):

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ... * * *
```

**Step 2** Create two more lazy seqences which are "windows" through which you look at the original, huge lazy sequence. First window contains only 12 elements (`t`), the other the rest of elements (`d`):

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ... * * *
t t t t t t t t t t t t t d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d ... d d d
```

**Step 3 - out of memory scenario** - you evaluate `[(count d) (count t)]`. So, first you count elements in `d`, then in `t`. What will happen is that you will go through all values starting at the first element of `d` and realize them (marked as `!`):

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * ! * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ... * * *
t t t t t t t t t t t t t d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d ... d d d 
                          ^
                         start here and move right ->

* * * * * * * * * * * * * ! ! * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ... * * *
t t t t t t t t t t t t t d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d ... d d d 
                            ^

* * * * * * * * * * * * * ! ! ! * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ... * * *
t t t t t t t t t t t t t d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d ... d d d 
                              ^

                     ...

; this is theoretical end of counting process which will never happen
; because of OutOfMemoryError
* * * * * * * * * * * * * ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ... ! ! !
t t t t t t t t t t t t t d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d ... d d d 
                                                                    ^
```

Problem is that all the realized values (`!`) are being retained, because the head of the collection (first 12 elements) are still needed - we still need to evaluate `(count t)`. This consumes a lot of memory causing JVM to crash.

**Step 3 - valid scenario** - this time you evaluate `[(count t) (count d)]`. So we first want to count elements in smaller, **head** sequence:

```
! * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ... * * *
t t t t t t t t t t t t t d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d ... d d d 
^
start here and move right ->

                        ! * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ... * * *
t t t t t t t t t t t t t d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d ... d d d 
                        ^
```

Then, we count elements in `d` sequence. Compiler knows that elements from `t` aren't needed anymore, so it can garbage collect them freeing up the memory:

```
                          ! * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ... * * *
t t t t t t t t t t t t t d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d ... d d d 
                          ^

                            ! * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ... * * *
t t t t t t t t t t t t t d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d ... d d d 
                            ^

                     ...

                                                            ...     !
t t t t t t t t t t t t t d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d ... d d d 
                                                                    ^
```

Now we can see that, because elements from `t` weren't needed anymore, compiler was able to clear memory as it went through the large sequence.

Comment: Thanks very much for this kamituel.  I understood Michał Marczyk's excellent answer, but this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

An important addition to the final example:

```clj
(let [[t d] (split-with #(< % 12) (range 1e8))]
    [(count d)])
```

> Back to the final example, this doesn't work, because t is not actually used anywhere and unused locals are not handled by the locals clearing process.

It's not the case anymore. Since Clojure 1.9 unused destructured locals are cleared. See [CLJ-1744](https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/CLJ-1744) for more details.